# How to register a concrete class implementation without invalidating generic autofac registration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

When registering a concrete **named** implementation with autofac, it breaks the generic one.
I need to be able to preserve generic implementation.

I am trying to register a separate Singleton instance apart from the one given by generic.

I've succesfully registed a generic interface implementation using autofac

```
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FruitSupplier<>))
            .As(typeof(IFruitSupplier<>))
            .SingleInstance();
```

But when adding a contrete **named** one on top of it

```
              .As(typeof(IFruitSupplier<>))
              .Named<string>(nameof(Service1)) // <--- named!
              .SingleInstance();
```

it breaks the generic implementation.

```
 builder.RegisterType(typeof(FruitSupplier<>))
                .As(typeof(IFruitSupplier<>))
                .Named<string>(nameof(Service1))
                .SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<Service1>()
                .As<IService1>()
                .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "appleStore",
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IFruitSupplier<Apple>>(nameof(Service1))
                ))
                .SingleInstance();
```

Here are my classes

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1(IFruitSupplier<Apple> appleStore)
    {            
    }    
}
```

```
    public class Apple : IFruit
    {
        public Apple(ISuppliers suppliers)
        {
        }
    }
```

```
public class Pear : IFruit
{
    public Pear(ISuppliers suppliers)
    {
    }
}
```

```
    public class FruitSupplier<T> : IFruitSupplier<T> where T : IFruit
    {
    }
```

```
var appleSupplierGenericSingleton = scope.Resolve<IFruitSupplier<Apple>>();

var serviceWithItsOwnAppleSupplierSingleton = scope.Resolve<Service1>();
```

How would I register **named** autofac implementation without breaking existing generic one?

Thanks!

Comment: in my case the problem that I'm trying to solve is getting a separate instance of db-client with different parameters.

Comment: When you say "it breaks," what do you mean? (Add that to your question. If there are exceptions, also add those.) Do you want the same name for every closed generic that comes out of the registration? Or is it only one closed registration you need named? (Put that in your question.)

Comment: sorry, by "breaks" I meant that if I ask for a generic service registration, the service comes back as null